# Build And Push Image To GHCR From CircleCI

Tags: circleci

At steps:

export CR_PAT='xxx'
echo $CR_PAT | docker login ghcr.io -u xxx --password-stdin

When use this code to build and push image, my personal access token on github removed itself. How to do it in CircleCI?

The error show like this: Error response from daemon: Get "https://ghcr.io/v2/": denied: denied

Get good and fast answer